# Any Ideas for a Permanent Resource Monitor Program?

Tags: memory, resources, cpu, monitor

Hey, while programming stuff, I have found that it is often very helpful to have some type of program constantly open to see if you have a memory leak, CPU overusage, etc.

The current resource monitor I use is the one that comes with W7. However, this program is more supposed to be used once in a while to see whats wrong with the system, not as a constant window open for monitoring system stats.

Any suggestions for an alternative program would be great! I'm looking for some type of program that doesn't use much resources, monitors CPU, RAM, and if possible network usage.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) is a pretty good alternative for continuous monitoring. If you need more detailed memory information for a given process including diffing capabilities, [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533) is great.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out Process Explorer!